# Changing the place of contents in toc with scrreprt

Tags: koma-script, tocbasic

I need to change “contents” word to the right. How can I do it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[listof=numbered]{scrreprt}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\appendix
\listoffigures
\chapter{Appendix chapter 1}
\chapter{Appendix chapter 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: KOMA-Script classes load and use package `tocbasic` by default. Package `tocstyle` is obsolete.

Comment: You tagged the question [tag:tocstyle] and the (now removed) example used `scrreprt`. People can't read your mind: it you use `book`, you should say so and provide minimal code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Remark:** My answer bases on the original MWE (using `scrreprt` class`) in the original question. Unfortunately the question was completely changed and the MWE was removed.

`scrreprt` loads package `tocbasic`, so you can use

```latex
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{%
  \renewcommand\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}%
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[listof=numbered]{scrreprt}

\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{%
  \renewcommand\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\appendix
\listoffigures
\chapter{Appendix chapter 1}
\chapter{Appendix chapter 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I happen to be using Book class in my thesis. Does it work anyway l?

Comment: My answer is a KOMA-Script solution regarding the MWE in the original question. Please restore your original content title and content of the question and ask a new question regarding `book` class.